# Azure WebJobs with Entity Framework job Parallelism

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an Azure webjob that's deployed with my MVC azure web app.  This job has two queue triggered functions, one that takes a PDF file and breaks it into individual page images and then a second that processes the individual pages.  I am using EF 6 and Unity on both the web site and in the webjob.

Using the IJobActivator option I have no problems injecting my DbContext and UoW/Services/Repositories into the webjob.  The problem seems to come when I attempt to run the webjob in parallel.  If I set the webjob config options to config.Queues.BatchSize = 1, everything is fine -- but slow (serial, one page at a time).  If I up the BatchSize to anything above 1, then I get errors along the line of "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed".  Since the DbContext is injected, I tried messing with the LifetimeManager options to see if that was the problem -- no change.  The error says that I need to ensure that all of my EF calls use "await" (are async), but they are...so that does not seem to be the problem.

The usefulness of the webjob will be seriously diminished if I cannot run it in parallel.  Any thoughts?  Would I be better off ditching EF and DbContext in the webjob and just use ADO.Net to go directly to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear that you can't have multiple outstanding async operations against the same DbContext simultaneously. Since you definitely want to maintain your job parallelism (i.e. don't set BatchSize to 1), you should probably just use a single new DbContext per job function invocation. DbContext is lightweight so this shouldn't be an issue for you.

Also the official [DbContext documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx) offers the following guidance on managing DbContext instances in WebApps: **"When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request."** That guidance applies in your WebJob case.

Comment: Your comment has forced me to think about what I was doing.  I was running the webjob in locally in debug mode via VS (but talking to live Storage Queues since queue triggers can't be emulated).  Perhaps that is what is causing the problem since it's not really running the job within the true web app environment.  I have changed the unity config to "PerRequestLifetimeManager" and I am going o publish to azure for real to see how it works.

Comment: Ok, so when I moved this to "real" Azure, I have run into a separate problem (perhaps to be posed separately).  The web app runs fine and DB is operating normally.  As soon as the WebJob is triggered and it goes to access the DB, the database gets nuked.  The DB is there, but ALL tables/data are deleted and exceptions start flying.  I restored the DB and tried again, same result.  My DbContext initializer is "null" so it should not try to do anything along those lines.  Thoughts?

Comment: Well, I'd say double check in your WebJob code that you're not accidentally using an initializer - not many other things that could be wiping your DB like that. You're saying you have an explicit call to `Database.SetInitializer<T>(null)` for your context? You could also run the WebJob locally and use VS intellitrace to see what statements are being executed when.

Comment: Yes, I have an explicit call to Database.SetInitializer<T>(null) in my context constructor.  When running locally, everything works except the original issue of the parallel access and related exceptions.  I will go back to running locally and see what inellitrace finds.

Comment: I needed to keep the DbContext lifecycle within the specific WebJob method.  Before I was using DI and the Unity container and injection was happening higher up, I think that was the issue.  I got rid of that, did a using statement directly on the DbContext and directly instantiated the services and repos inside the specific WebJob method.  Now, at least locally, everything works perfect, even when running tons of parallel WebJob instances.  HOWEVER, on Azure everything still blows up because the DB STILL gets nuked when the job starts. I can't run Intellitrace because I don't have Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the solution to the parallelism problem comes down to keeping the DbContext lifetime to within the single method of the WebJob because EF isn't thread-safe.  Trying to use Unity and IJobActivator kept that stuff at a higher level (outside the method) and even changing the LifetimeManager had no effect.  By getting rid of Unity and just creating a "using" statement inside of the WebJob on the DbContext, it kept everything safe and worked.

The loss/reset of the SQL database on production Azure seems to be related to EF DB initializers and migrations.  I am going to start another question on that since it's not directly related to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure your unity registration ?
I think if you want to inject your DbContext, you should just use a registration that create a **new instance per call**. Each time a new message arrives in your queue, the framework will use the IJobActivator to get the dependencies.

I've got an implementation of the IJobActivator using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html)

```
/// <summary>
/// An activator that uses <see cref="SimpleInjector"/> to return instance of a job type.
/// </summary>
public class SimpleInjectorJobActivator : IJobActivator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the container to resolve dependencies.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Container _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new instance of the <see cref="SimpleInjectorJobActivator"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="container">The <see cref="Container"/> to resolve dependencies.</param>
    public SimpleInjectorJobActivator(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of a job type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The job type.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// A new instance of the job type.
    /// </returns>
    public T CreateInstance<T>()
    {
        return (T)_container.GetInstance(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

If you create a job processor per queue trigger, you can create two classes like that :

```
public class MyJobProcessor1
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public MyJobProcessor1(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }


    public void Run([QueueTrigger("my-queue1")] BrokeredMessage message)
    {

    }
}
```

And my main function:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Register my dependency, by default simple injector create a new instance per call
    var container = new Container();
    container.Register(() => new MyDbContext());
    container.Verify();

    // Configure the job host
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration
    {
        JobActivator = new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(container)
    };
    // Run the host
    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Every time a new message arrives, the IJobActivator return a new instance of the DbContext as registered with my IoC container.